# Музыка зациклилась на первой секунде. Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Имеется окно с кнопками и другими различными элементами. При запуске должна воспроизводиться музыка, но вместо этого она почему-то зацикливается на первой секунде.

```
from tkinter import *
import pyglet

def music():
    sound = pyglet.media.load('mysound.mp3')
    sound.play()

music()
```

Comment: Вероятно, после этого кода вы не запускаете pyglet event loop и соответственно не даёте ему возможности подгрузить больше музыки в буфер, вот и играет та единственная секунда которая успела попасть в буфер

Comment: да, так и есть. А как решить это, я даже если один раз вызову эту функцию при нажатии кнопки, он все равно будет зациклено играть

Comment: у меня в конце стоит строка tk.mainloop() А после того, как я добавил pyglet.event.loop() ничего, к сожалению, не поменялось